# How to sum up subtractions of 2 numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, sum, subtraction

> You are given a list of how many people are at the store adding on a list every time there are changes. For example - at the very beginning there are 0, then 2 come in so there are 2 people in the store and 4 when 2 more come in, but 1 when 3 leave, then again 3 when 2 more come in. So the input list would look like 0 2 4 1 3. You have to make a program that counts the total number of people who have been in the store, in this case, it would be 6.

```
a=[int(i)for i in input().split()]
for i in range (1,len(a)):
    if a[i] > a[i-1]:
        b = a[i] - a[i-1]
```

Is as far as I am getting. I subtracted if the number was greater than the previous one and now I have to sum up all the subtractions. How do I do that?

Comment: You need something to store the sum of the values of `b` in

Comment: So what have you actually tried to solve the issue? I see the part that works, but what have you done about the part that doesn't? This isn't a code writing or tutorial service you know.

Comment: You could put every subtraction result in a list (`b.append(a[i] - a[i-1])`), then sum that list at the end: `sum(b)`. Or just keep a sum to which you add `b` every iteration.

Comment: Impossible to solve. If three people can leave at the same time, then also two people can leave and one can come in all at the same time, indistinguishable from just one person leaving. Plus the same people could come in and leave multiple times, indistinguishable from different people coming in and leaving.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `total` variable. Start it at `a[0]` add to it any time you calculate `b`.

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
total = a[0]
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] > a[i-1]:
        b = a[i] - a[i-1]
        total += b
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you should be adding all the *positive* pairwise differences.

```
a = [0] + [int(i) for i in input().split()]

total = sum(max(0, y-x) for x, y in zip(a, a[1:]))
```

The additional `0` at the front takes car eof the case where there are people at the shop at the start.